# Git in Android Studio: get version from repository not available

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I start to use Git in Android Studio. Once I change the files I am committing them. But then I want to get old version of file and load it on Android Studio. I use "Get", on context menu when I clicked the right mouse button and do it. But now I run Android Studio and see next:
[image]

Why "Get" is not available?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Get is still unavailable for the other versions listed in your screenshot.

If it is unavailable only for the latest version, that simply means you already have that version in your working tree.

It is isn't, try going back to command-line and:

```
cd /path/to/parent/folder
git log -- yourGile
git checkout <SHA1> -- afile
```

Comment: "Get" unavailable for all versions

Comment: @user3499878 is that file visible in the current version of your repo? (Or was it deleted)

Comment: Which is file? That file, which I commit? Last file that I have commited visible in the current version

Comment: @user3499878 you mentions " I want to get old version of file": that file.

Comment: This problem not only for this project, in another project "Get" also unavailable

Comment: @user3499878 hence my suggestion to fallback to command-line: there will be more information that way

Comment: Yes, I want to get old version of my commited file

Comment: If I click in "Log" "Checkout Revision" my older file open and "HEAD" set for choosed commit. But maybe is it not correctly to get older version?

Comment: It checks out the all commit, not just one file. Any other files part of more recent commits would be reverted to that older commit. If that is what you want, then it is good. If you need just one file, then it isn't.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand why "Get" unavailable